# Can't set PFTableViewCell imageView?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm trying to display an icon for each PFTableViewCell based on the imageView property which doesn't work. The code I'm using is below which throws the follow error, "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject) -> PFTableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! i!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = PFTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = "Some Label"

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Another label"

    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon.png")

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Which line causes the crash?

Comment: cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "icon.png") causes the crash.

Comment: Is "icon.png" a local file, or is it stored in your Parse.com database?

Comment: Please paste what the console says after the crash.

Comment: "icon.png" is a local file and the console reads "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Your crash is linked to the imageView being nil.

I guess this is a bug with PFTableViewCell: it does not "see" the standard imageView from the "Basic" style, and cannot create the corresponding PFImageView (I opened an issue with ParseUI).

Generally speaking, it's better to set your line like so:

```
cell.imageview?.image
```

then you won't have the crash.
You won't have the image either, but that's because of Parse's PFTableViewCell ...

If you want your code to work, you need to create a custom cell, with an imageView that you need to set as a PFImageView. This way, there will indeed be an imageView, and the whole PFTableViewCell file loading works perfectly.